# Posts using index.php instead of single.php

Tags: wordpress

Ok this question has been asked numerous times but none of the answers have solved my issue. Just to find out the exact problem, I am here to get your help. My posts are using index.php instead of single.php to display.

index.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file.
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package AWE
 */

get_header();
?>

    <div id="primary" class="container">
        <main id="main" class="main-content col-md-9" role="main">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php

                    /*
                     * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
        </main><!-- #main -->
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div><!-- #primary -->


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

single.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts.
 *
 * @package AWE
 */

get_header(); ?>
<!-- Blog head -->
    <section id="blog-head" class="blog-head">
        <div class="blog-head-section parallax-style clearfix">
            <div class="parallax-overlay">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="fluid-section section-padding">
                        <h2 class="section-title"><?php echo esc_html(zels_get_option('blog_section_title')) ?></h2>
                        <div class="section-details text-center">
                            <?php echo esc_html(zels_get_option('blog_section_des')) ?>
                        </div><!-- /.section-details -->    
                    </div><!-- /.fluid-section section-padding -->
                </div><!-- /.container -->
            </div><!-- /.parallax-overlay -->
        </div><!-- /.blog-head-section -->
    </section><!-- /#blog-head -->
    <!-- Blog head End -->

<div class="content-area">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Main Container  -->
            <div id="main-content" class="main-content col-md-12">

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' ); ?>

                    <?php
                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                        comments_template();
                    endif;
                    ?>

                <?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>
            </div>

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div>

    </div><!-- #container -->
</div><!-- #content-area -->


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It was working fine previously until the client updated the content of the posts. I would like to know in what scenario does the posts use various templates for displaying in front-end.

Comment: Has the form action been changed to index.php or blank ? in that case it won't use  single.php anymore

Comment: @Tomm How do I check that?

Comment: If you want to get or post from a form you will have to specify a action in your form, this is mostly done in the header of your form so it would look something like <form action="index.php">

Comment: Ohh no. I haven't specified any form tag in my header file.

Comment: Not in your header file....... You are trying to post from an input or something i assume. Those things are in a form and that form has a line called <form action="">